# Python sort list of dicts

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have list of dicts and those dicts also have dict objects. This is the list:

[image: my list]

This is a simple sample of my list:

```
result = [ {'parameters' : {'buy_period':10, 'sell_period':20}, 'profit_result': {'base_sharpe_ratio': 0.5, 'base_calmar_ratio': 2.2}},{'parameters' : {'buy_period':20, 'sell_period':30},'profit_result': {'base_sharpe_ratio': 1.5, 'base_calmar_ratio': 3.2} }, {'parameters' : {'buy_period':30, 'sell_period':40}, 'profit_result': {'base_sharpe_ratio': 2.5, 'base_calmar_ratio': 4.2} } ]
```

I can sort the list by

```
results.sort(key=itemgetter('sort_metric'))
```

I want to sort the list based on an inner dict value, for example, by 'base_sharpe_ratio'. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you please add the simple dict to your question?

Comment: @Serhii Added. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```py
results.sort(key = lambda dic: dic.get('profit_result').get('base_sharpe_ratio', -float('inf')))
```

Comment: The reason is, you have to be sure all of your dictionaries include 'base_sharpe_ratio' key. Error happens because at least one of them does not.

Comment: What do you want to happen with the dictionaries that do not have a keyword, by which you want to sort them?

Comment: All elements have `base_sharpe_ratio`. It's impossible that they do not have that key.

Comment: Try `results.sort(key = lambda dic: dic['base_sharpe_ratio'] if 'base_sharpe_ratio' in dic else -float('inf'))`

Comment: Better yet, `results.sort(key = lambda dic: dic.get('base_sharpe_ratio', -float('inf'))`

Comment: These are not working. They are not producing errors nor doing what I want. The previous order remains the same.

Comment: Please remember that `base_sharpe_ratio` is a value of dict which is a value of another dict. So, the outer dict does not have `base_sharpe_ratio `but the inner one has. That's why adding `-float('inf')` code prevented the error. The outer dicts do not have the `base_sharpe_ratio` so they are all sorted based on `-float('inf')`

Comment: Based on your example, this should work `results.sort(key = lambda dic: dic.get('profit_result').get('base_sharpe_ratio', -float('inf')))`

Comment: @kuco23 Hey, this works. Thanks! Update your answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
inner_key = 'base_sharpe_ratio'
results.sort(key=lambda x: x['profit_result'][inner_key])
```

Comment: @ruso_ro1 This works but Kuco's answer was earlier. I'll upvote this, too.